# c# How to handle Null Exception without using try catch to direct code?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to write better code with out using try catch to direct code and without using empty catches but I am having a hard time.

Here is my code snipplet

```
    public static List<string> GetProcessList()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (AudioSession session in AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions())
        {

            try
            {
                if (session != null && session.Process != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(session.Process.ProcessName))
                {
                    result.Add(session.Process.ProcessName);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                LogManager.Instance().TbLogger.LogError("GetAllSessions " + ex.StackTrace);
                ex.ToExceptionless().Submit();
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

How can this be re-written so it does not look like this.

```
    public static List<string> GetProcessList()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (AudioSession session in AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions())
        {

            try
            {
                if (session != null && session.Process != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(session.Process.ProcessName))
                {
                    result.Add(session.Process.ProcessName);

                }
            }
            catch (System.NullReferenceException)
            {
                //don't add to the list
                //can this empty catch be avoided?
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                LogManager.Instance().TbLogger.LogError("GetAllSessions " + ex.StackTrace);
                ex.ToExceptionless().Submit();
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

Or like this....

```
    public static List<string> GetProcessList()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (AudioSession session in AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions())
        {

            try
            {
                if (session != null && session.Process != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(session.Process.ProcessName))
                {
                    result.Add(session.Process.ProcessName);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               //do nothing
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

.

Update: Sorry I forgot to add the error I was having...

Here is the stack trace.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at myControl.AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
```

How can this function be re-written correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to have prevented every situation where there could be a NullReference, so why add a catch for that? Also I don't understand why in the last code block you added the empty catch...if you want to avoid that don't write that (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: I updated the code above with the stack trace.

Comment: The null ref is happening in code you didn't post. Your try/catch stuff is *after* the exception occurs, so it doesn't help you at all. Do you have the code for AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()? If so, include that.

Comment: I don't recall this error being clear whether the null reference is `myControl` or `AudioUtilities`

Comment: as far as I can tell AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions is part of the OS.  for windows 7 and above.  the Error happens on 6.1.7601.65536 a windows 7 machine.  My first snipplet does not work.. the second 2 snipplets above do work but I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Are you sure about the location? I see [on this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938934/controlling-applications-volume-by-process-id) that someone wrote a very similar AudioUtilities class. If you right-click go to definition, what DLL does it say the code is located in (should be in comment at top of meta-data if using Visual Studio)?

Comment: @Anssssss here is my using   = using CoreAudioApi;
using CoreAudioApi.Interfaces;  I don't reference anything it just automaticly finds it.

Comment: Well, you're referencing some code, what it is exactly doesn't matter I guess. I think you're describing an impossibility though, because you say the GetAllSessions() method throws an exception in the first code block, but doesn't in the other two. That shouldn't be possible since all your try-catch blockery doesn't happen until after the GetAllSessions call (and that should only happen once). I'd suggest debugging it and stepping through. Can't help you any more though since I don't know where you got the code so can't reproduce. Try right-click go to definition. It should tell you the dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking for null references, you can check every '.' and function*. Here are those in your code:

- AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions(), is AudioUtilities a type, an instance variable, or a static variable?
- session.Process, but you check for session being null before this.
- session.Process.ProcessName, but you check for session.Process being null before this.
- result.Add(...), but you initialized result above here.
- result.Add(session.Process.ProcessName), but you check for session.Process.ProcessName being null before this.

So, you've covered all the places that could cause this except for AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions() and if any of these could be modified on another thread. If that is the case, you can store each value before testing for it being null:

```
    public static List<string> GetProcessList()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        List<AudioSession> sessions = null;
        if (AudioUtilities != null)
            sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions();

        if (sessions != null)
        {
            foreach (AudioSession session in sessions)
            {
                Process process = null; //guessing type here
                if (session != null)
                    process = session.Process;
                string processName = null;
                if (process != null)
                    processName = process.ProcessName;

                if (processName != null)
                    result.Add(processName);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This seems like overkill, but should be safe. This protects you from the (admittedly unlikely) event of data changing between the check and the de-reference.

*Unless I've forgotten something, although I don't see anything that applies here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using comparatos to check if the reference is null before accessing it, you will never get a exception.

```
public static List<string> GetProcessList()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    foreach (AudioSession session in AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions())
    {
        if(session == null || session.Process == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(session.Process.ProcessName))
            continue;

        result.Add(session.Process.ProcessName);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Unless your GetAllSessions method is Throwing the exception - but it's not in a try clausule.