# COM Objects C# Casting MMDeviceEnumerator to IMMDeviceEnumerator InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, com

I have no experience with COM Imports and am just working with someone else's code that wasn't working for me

The line of code that is throwing the InvalidCastException:

```
    IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
```

COM Imports:

```
[Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
internal class MMDeviceEnumerator
{
}

[Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow dataFlow, DEVICE_STATE dwStateMask, out IMMDeviceCollection ppDevices);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role, out IMMDevice ppEndpoint);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetDevice([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwstrId, out IMMDevice ppDevice);

    [PreserveSig]
    int RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(IMMNotificationClient pClient);

    [PreserveSig]
    int UnregisterEndpointNotificationCallback(IMMNotificationClient pClient);
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not very close, you are creating a .NET class.  Letting the CLR know that this is actually a COM declaration and implemented elsewhere requires using the [ComImport] directive.  I'll give you the minimum required declarations:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
{
    // etc..
}

public static class MMDeviceEnumeratorFactory {
    private static readonly Guid MMDeviceEnumerator = new Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E");

    public static IMMDeviceEnumerator CreateInstance() {
        var type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(MMDeviceEnumerator);
        return (IMMDeviceEnumerator)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = MMDeviceEnumeratorFactory.CreateInstance();
```

Do strongly avoid using [PreserveSig], you want a loud bang when a method fails.  Do note that this interface is already wrapped by the NAudio library.

Comment: That seems to solve the Exception issue, I removed the [PreserveSig] from the COM coclass. so was I just casting it using the incorrect method?

Comment: Starting with the class declaration just got you completely on the wrong path.  Please close your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out :)

Answer (score -1):

I guess your MMDeviceEnumerator class should implement the interface.

In other words, change

```
internal class MMDeviceEnumerator
{
}
```

To:

```
internal class MMDeviceEnumerator : IMMDeviceEnumerator
{
}
```

Comment: I get these errors:      Error 2 'changeSpotifyVolume.MMDeviceEnumerator' does not implement interface member 'changeSpotifyVolume.IMMDeviceCollection.GetCount(out int)' 
Error 1 'changeSpotifyVolume.MMDeviceEnumerator' does not implement interface member 'changeSpotifyVolume.IMMDeviceCollection.Item(int, out changeSpotifyVolume.IMMDevice)'