# Can´t mute windows media player by process id

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-10, windows-media-player

I am using the following code of answer 2 to mute external players like vlc or windows media player.

[Controlling Application's Volume: By Process-ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938934/controlling-applications-volume-by-process-id)

The VLC player is muted properly. But windows media player does not.

Visually it is mutated correctly as shown in the following image. But I still hear the sound through the speakers. When I remove the mute (mute of the application) and I put it manually using the mouse it is muted correctly.

[image]

[image]

```
       public static void mute()
        {              

            for(int i = 0;i<playerList.Length;i++)
            {                    
                var hWnd = FindWindow(null, playerList[i]);
                if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Mute " + playerList[i] + " Error_1");
                    continue;
                }


                uint pID;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out pID);
                if (pID == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Mute " + playerList[i] + " Error_2");
                    continue;
                }




                VolumeMixer.SetApplicationMute((int)pID, true);
                Console.WriteLine("Mute " + playerList[i] + " Ok PID: " + pID);


            }


        }
```

Comment: It may not be relevant, but i once wrote a tool for the WMP and had similar issues with controlling the volume level. It turned out that the WMP had always more than one audio session, so i had to set the volume on each of those sessions. You may need to change the implementation of the 'VolumeMixer' class in a way that every session with the WMP process id is muted.

Comment: I have performed the following test: I have obtained all running processes "Process.GetProcesses()" and I have mute the volume of all process. The same problem happens. The bar is lowered but I'm still listening.

Comment: That's not exactly what i meant. In the `GetVolumeObject(int pid)` method: instead of returning only one session volume control, one may have to return a list containing all `ISimpleAudioVolume` that have the process id of the WMP and set the mute state on all of them.

Comment: It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

@Streamline said in comment:

> In the GetVolumeObject(int pid) method: instead of returning only one
>   session volume control, one may have to return a list containing all
>   ISimpleAudioVolume that have the process id of the WMP and set the
>   mute state on all of them.

That was the problem. Now it works perfectly.