# Volume Mixer — Get applications name, and their process ID

Tags: vb.net, volume, windows, mixer

Is there any way to get applications name and their process ID from Volume Mixer?

[image: Volume Mixer]

And if it's not possible to get their Process ID, is it possible to manipulate their volume level?

Comment: There's some code in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer that might get you started

Comment: it has nothing to do with getting applications name and their Process ID from Volume Mixer

Comment: Are you sure?  That C# sample enumerates through all the applications and actually filters based on their name, look at the EnumerateApplications method.  It looks for a particular application and then adjusts the volume of that application which is exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way for filtering and displaying processes if they're in VolumeMixer. I'm using VolumeMixer class, which you can find here in the answers [Controlling Application's Volume: By Process-ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938934/controlling-applications-volume-by-process-id).

Also, you have to add this line at the beggining of your code.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Displaying and filtering processes if they're in Volume Mixer.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process process in processlist)
            if (VolumeMixer.GetApplicationVolume(process.Id) != null)
                lstProcesses.Items.Add(process.ProcessName + " # " + process.MainWindowTitle + " # " + process.Id);
```

So now, with the same class you can change the volume  of applications by using their Process ID.
Example:

```
VolumeMixer.SetApplicationVolume(process.Id, 50f);
```