# C# Core Audio API - Only manually entered int working

Tags: c#, .net, windows, audio

I'm using the Windows Core Audio API, with a wrapper from [Controlling Application's Volume: By Process-ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938934/controlling-applications-volume-by-process-id#answer-25584074)

In this test method here, which sets the volume of a application (by ProcessID):

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanChangeVolume()
{
    VolumeMixer.SetApplicationVolume(19348, 50f);
}
```

If i manually enter `19348` into the code, the function works as it should.

But if i pass a dynamic value, like so...

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanChangeVolume()
{
    foreach (AudioSession session in AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions())
    {
        if (session.Process != null)
        {
            VolumeMixer.SetApplicationVolume(session.ProcessId, 50f);
        }
    }
}
```

... i get the following error by the Core Audio API:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MMDeviceEnumerator' to type 'RemoteVolume.Server.MMDeviceEnumerator'.
```

Note: Printing out `session.ProcessId` is also working fine...

For Example: `session.ProcessId = 8508`, `VolumeMixer.SetApplicationVolume(8508, 50f)` is working fine

Comment: Can you step through both of your test functions with the debugger, and step in to the execution of `SetApplicationVolume` for each one to see exactly where the failure is occurring? I'm wondering if the first test succeeds because `19348` is not a valid process ID and it's bypassing the bad cast within `SetApplicationVolume`.

Comment: @ozeanix and the test function doesn't only succeed because of a invalid processID, it actually changes the volume...

Comment: Well, you're failing on the line where you're casting the `new MMDeviceEnumerator()` to `IMMDeviceEnumerator`, but that's not necessarily happening in C++ code. That could be because `MMDeviceEnumerator` and `IMMDeviceEnumerator` both need the `[ComVisible]` attribute applied to them, and the interface doesn't have it. I'm curious how it works in the first case and not in the second, though, because it should fail both times. Also, when you specify the hardcoded process ID, is there actually a process for it, or is the system master volume changing?

Comment: @ozeanix you're right it's failing at casting from `MMDeviceEnumerator` to `IMMDeviceEnumerator`, but funnily enough, it's working hardcoded. And yes, the applications volume is actually changing.

Comment: @ozeanix `[ComVisible(true)]` doesn't work for me...

Comment: @ozeanix I actually managed to do the same by just using the Windows Core Audio API in a seperate C++ Project... but thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I suppose that proves it's some kind of .NET COM interop problem since it works fine in C++! Glad you got it working.