# Getting the icon for an audio device

Tags: winapi

In the Sound Control Panel in Windows, and in the Volume Mixer, all audio devices have a specific icon set.

Is it possible to get which icon is set for a device through the Windows API?

[Sound Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDcnI.png)
[Volume Mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQM3T.png)

Comment: If you look that answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938934/controlling-applications-volume-by-process-id the AudioSession class has an IconPath property.

Comment: I tried that out after your suggestion, but it is not what I'm looking for.
For one, it operates on audio sessions, not audio devices.
For two, according to the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nf-audiopolicy-iaudiosessioncontrol-geticonpath) "If a client has not called IAudioSessionControl::SetIconPath to set the display icon, the string will be empty."

Comment: I believe what you see in the mixer is audio sessions, not devices. Anyway, in my code, I just didn't exposed all properties of audio devices but you can get them using the `Properties` dictionary. I've just modified my code and added an `IconPath` property on `AudioDevice` class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-deviceclass-iconpath

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm sure I tried that, but whatever, this does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Simon Mourier in the comments above, there is a PKEY that can access that data.

You can follow along with most of [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/device-properties) and just replace `PKEY_Device_FriendlyName`with `PKEY_DeviceClass_IconPath`.

In short, it's something like this:

```cpp
    // [...]

    IMMDevice *pDevice; // the device you want to look up
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IPropertyStore *pProps = NULL;
    PROPVARIANT varName;

    hr = pDevice->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, &pProps);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

    PropVariantInit(&varName);

    hr = pProps->GetValue(PKEY_DeviceClass_IconPath, &varName);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

    // [...]
```