# How to get IAudioSessionControl2 in windows-rs?

Tags: winapi, rust, windows-rs

I'm trying to write a [mute.fm](https://github.com/jaredsohn/mutefm)-like program in Rust, this is my first big project both using rust and winapi. I managed to get `IAudioSessionControl`, but it doesn't include process ID or name, so there is no way to know which application it is. `IAudioSessionControl2` has a `GetProcessID` method, but I can't find any way to obtain this interface.

It looks like in C# you can get it by just doing `IAudioSessionControl2 ctl2 = ctl as IAudioSessionControl2;`, where `ctl` is `IAudioSessionControl` (found this snippet in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938934/controlling-applications-volume-by-process-id)), but in Rust that's not as simple. `IAudioSessionControl2` can be converted into `IAudioSessionControl` using `From`, but not the other way around

This is the code I use, if it helps:

```rust
use std::ptr;
use windows::Win32::{Media::Audio::*, System::Com::*};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        CoInitialize(ptr::null()).unwrap();

        let enumerator: IMMDeviceEnumerator =
            CoCreateInstance(&MMDeviceEnumerator, None, CLSCTX_ALL).unwrap();
        let device = enumerator
            .GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eMultimedia)
            .unwrap();
        let manager: IAudioSessionManager2 = device.Activate(CLSCTX_ALL, ptr::null()).unwrap();
        let sessions = manager.GetSessionEnumerator().unwrap();

        for n in 0..sessions.GetCount().unwrap() {
            let session_control = sessions.GetSession(n).unwrap();
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do get IAudioSessionControl2 from IAudioSessionControl, you must use sessionControlRef->QueryInterface(...) (this is was C# does undercovers). Not sure how to do that in rust.

Comment: Unrelated note: You shouldn't really call `CoUninitialize`. Even though the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize) insists that each successful call to `CoInitialize[Ex]` must be balanced with a call to `CoUninitialize`, the latter has preconditions that are hard to maintain in practice. Just let the thread die and have the system clean up the mess afterwards.

Comment: Also unrelated, but if you have your `main` return a [`Result`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/type.Result.html) instead, all those `unwrap()`s turn into simple [`?`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-question-mark-operator)s.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, i know about the Result, just forgot about it in the moment, this was just a quick and dirty way to test the idea. `CoUninitialize` info is really helpful tho, removed it. Can you point me somewhere to read about what could go wrong with it? Or is it all just in the microsoft docs on this function? @iinspectable

Comment: I'll write up a full answer that covers this as well as how COM is exposed in the `windows` crate. As a cliffhanger: The call to `CoUninitialize` introduces a bug, not just in theory but in practice. I'll cover that as well. I'm assuming you aren't blocked by this issue anymore, so I'll take my fair time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You can take as much time as you'd like. Also uni just started so I haven even less spare hours to work on this so you have all the time in the world

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you need to use `.cast()` on the `IAudioSessionControl` like so, annotating the type explicitly

```rust
let session_control_2: IAudioSessionControl2 = session_control.cast().unwrap();
```

The documentation is not as clear as i would hope it to be. Thanks to the comment I decided to search for the `QueryInterface` on the `IAudioSessionControl` page and found the `.cast()` method

Comment: The [FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md) has the following entry, which describes this: [How do I query for a specific COM interface?](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-query-for-a-specific-com-interface). Basic familiarity with COM is assumed.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Well, I am only about 3 days in winapi and don't have anybody at hand to ask so stackoverflow it is. At least this way anyone struggling to do the same thing will have something to find on google later on